# Display ∀ symbol using unicode &#2220;

Tags: html, unicode

Please consider the following html:

```html
<p>&#2220;</p>
```

I expected to see the ∀ symbol, but instead saw a box in its place.

How do I correct this?

Comment: you can use `&forall;` instead of &#2220;

Comment: I would prefer to use the numeric code, if that's possible?

Comment: Lovely!  The decimal worked.  Thank you, Alex K.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turned_A#Encodings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct character entity for [U+2200](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2200/index.htm) is `&#x2200;` (hex) or equivalently `&#8704;` (decimal).

Comment: Yes.  That worked, thank you.  I was missing the 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

For using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your website you can add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
```

And inside `<body>` in your case:

`<p>$$\forall$$</p>` will give ∀

or any other math equation.

Comment: Thanks, but I was experimenting on something away from MathJax, so need to use the unicode chars.